# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError [Username and Password not accepted]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, spree

I've got this error on production when app is trying to send a confirmation email. The app is using spree.

```
    enter code herNet::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at

):
    `app/controllers/spree/user_registration_controller_decorator.rb:5:in `create`'
    e
```

Here it is a bit of my conf file in production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'mydomain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :user_name => 'myemailhere@gmail.com',
   :password => 'passwordhere',
   :authentication => :plain,
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

I'm sure about my email and pass. I'd also changed my settings at http://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and tried sending email after enabling access at https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.I don't know what else I can do. Maybe there is something about spree. I'm really unfamiliar with it.

Comment: It's a bit [less secure](http://12factor.net/config) to include your email and password in `production.rb` especially if you're using a version control system like git. Consider using the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use the following settings:

   ```
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
   config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => 'smtp.gmail.com',
     :user_name => "username@gmail.com",
     :password => "yourpassword",
     :authentication => :login,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have "Access for less secure apps" turned ON at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Go to https://g.co/allowaccess **from another device you have previously used to access your google account**.

Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14

Mail sending should work now.

**Tip for Spree Commerce:** Use https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings gem with the following settings:

[image: spree_mail_settings for gmail]